# Access VBA to send Outlook Email based on query

Tags: sql, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to create a button that when clicked will populate an outlook email "To" field based on a query.  Part of the query criteria is based on a few combo boxes. If I add the below criteria to the query I get this error when running the code - "Too few parameters. Expected 1."  If I do not reference the combo boxes in the query the code runs perfectly, except I am not able to limit who I am sending an email to based on the criteria.  I have opened the query by itself to see if maybe I referenced something incorrectly but it works fine.

I am new to working with Access - so I appreciate your patience if this is something very simple.

**VBA code:**

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rstEmail As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strAddresses As String
Dim Outlook

Set db = CurrentDb()


If bxContactType = "Principal" Then
    strSQL = "SELECT [Principal Email] FROM qry_EmailOut;"
    Set rstEmail = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    Do While Not rstEmail.EOF
        Outlook = Outlook + rstEmail("Principal Email") + ";"
        rstEmail.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

**Query Criteria:**

[forms]![Email Lists]![bxState]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to filter the query in the where clause as follows:

```
strSQL = "SELECT [Principal Email] FROM qry_EmailOut WHERE <column name> = " & Chr(34) & [forms]![Email Lists]![bxState] & Chr(34)
```

The following link provide additional information:
General overview:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281870

Specific related Q/A:
http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=192635

Regards,

Comment: Thank you! That did it.  I previously tried adding the Where clause in the code but I had it inside the quotation marks and didn't have the formatting exactly right. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: By the way - thank you for the links... they were very helpful!